# mvc3 how can i increase the login time, I have tried and been wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logout, form-authentication

I have been trying to extend the login time of every user who logins but for some reason after 15 to 20 minutes or so it logs me out. I want to get the logout time to 300 minutes as people actually create articles on the website so they need time what I have so far is this...

```
 // this is when users login i want the timeout to be 300 minutes automatically

  FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(model.Email, model.RememberMe, 300);
                    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

and this is my web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".loog" loginUrl="~/Account/login" timeout="300" protection="All" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
</authentication>
```

what could be the reason why i get logged out every 20 minutes.. any help would be great !

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET Session to store some user details?

Comment: no I am not, I just want the login user not be kicked out every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In `web.config`

```
 <system.web>

   .......

   <sessionState timeout="300"></sessionState>

 </system.web>
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: i will try that and see how it goes.